# Debug injected process

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, debugging, dll-injection

I've got a problem with debugging a DLL, which is injected via a VC++ DLL onto a WPF-Application. The injecting works fine. Here a guide from the start to the problem :

1. I start debugging a WPF testapplication (.Net 4.0 / x86).
2. After starting a `ButtonClickEvent` starts a small ConsoleApplication, which starts injecting via a C++ function
   3.For test purposes the program stops at a `Debugger.Break()` call. Up to this point all right.
3. When I try to step forwards, it's still working, but when I reach a `foreach` loop or a call to another class, managed by injected DLL, the debugger stops working immediately, and WPF application is closed.

If I run these code without stopping with a BreakPoint, there is no error.
I have no idea, whats my fault, so I hope you can give me some approach to solve it.

Comment: Is the VC++ dll compiled for debug?

Comment: Yeah it is, all .pds are still available

Comment: When the debugger stops working, do you get any errors?

Comment: No there is no error, not if I debug as well as I run without debug, I only got the message : "Debugger have to stop working" (similar), and the output says : thread "wpfapplication.exe" stops with code -2xxxxxxxxx (sry, I'm actually not in front of program)

Comment: Look at application event logs

Comment: Verify two things: if the point of crash is exactly the same line of code each time execution is aborted, if there are other threads running in the background that could be hitting a point where they deliberately call application exit directly or indirectly.

Comment: Can you set breakpoint into injected DLL where code pass call from exe? What stop code? `-2xxxxxxxxx`

Comment: @ Murali: No matter where I set the breakpoint, it's always same procedure. First it stops on breakpoint, but I can't watch variables or something else, and if I want to step to next line, Debugger is closed.The ouput exit code is : -2147023895 (0x800703e9)

Comment: @Kooki `0x000003E9`
`ERROR_STACK_OVERFLOW` Recursion too deep the stack overflowed. Ironically.

Comment: @sergmat a SOF is inexplicable to me, cause there is no recursion on these point, above all the programm normally runs to end if I not set any breakpoint

Comment: @Kooki I think source code would be useful for debugging this issue.

Comment: I don't know if code is useful, cause it stops everytime I want to step through a foreach.I noticed, that I can debug it step for step, if I use a Disassembly ( but don't know why it sometime is possible to use it, sometimes not). If I use normal debugging, my application ends with : Das Programm "[8892] WpfApplication1.exe: Systemeigen" wurde mit Code -2147023895 (0x800703e9) beendet.